# Ask - How to use the word 'params' in 'PostJsonAsync' Flurl

Tags: c#, json, post, flurl

I am using **flurl** to retrieve data in the url. How to use the word **params** in **PostJsonAsync**? The problem I get is `identifier expected: 'params' is keyword`, if I use a word other than 'params' there is no problem.

```
            .PostJsonAsync(new
            {
                variables = (new
                {
                    params = "&ob=23&identifier=handphone-tablet_aksesoris-handphone&sc=66&user_id=0&rows=60&start=1&source=directory&device=desktop&page=1&related=true&st=product&safe_search=false"
                }),
            })
```

Comment: @Hulk I think it's just a wrong tag, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you want to use a C# reserved word as a property name, just prefix it with `@`:

```
new 
{
    @params = "..."
}
```